# Cauchy-Riemann equations to check differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis

Check the Cauchy-Riemann equations for the functions $f$ defined below. Where are the functions differentiable?

a) $f(x+iy)=e^x\cos(y)+ie^x\sin(y)$

b) $f(x+iy)=2x+xy^2i$

For a) I let $u=e^x\cos(y)$ and $v=e^2\sin(y)$ and checked the partial derivatives w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ for each which were all continuous and the Cauchy-Riemann conditions held true. I also found the second derivatives for each and they were all continuous too. So that means $f$ is differentiable right? But where? Because we were not given a domain or anything.

For b) the conditions do not hold true for any $x$ or $y$ value so does that mean it is not differentiable anywhere?

Comment: For $(a)$, it means everywhere i.e. all over $\mathbb{C}$. For $(b)$ it means nowhere i.e. $f$ not differentiable at any point of the complex plane.

Comment: So it is differentiable everywhere? for a)

Comment: Yes. I have mentioned it.